# Restful API - handling large amounts of data

Tags: web-services, api, rest

I have written my own Restful API and am wondering about the best way to deal with large amounts of records returned from the API.

For example, if I use `GET` method to `myapi.co.uk/messages/` this will bring back the XML for all message records, which in some cases could be 1000's.  This makes using the API very sluggish.

Can anyone suggest the best way of dealing with this? Is it standard to return results in batches and to specify batch size in the request?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can change your API to include additional parameters to limit the scope of data returned by your application.

For instance, you could add `limit` and `offset` parameters to fetch just a little part. This is how pagination can be done in accordance with REST. A request like this would result in fetching 10 resources from the messages collection, from 21st to 30th. This way you can ask for a specific portion of a huge data set:

```
myapi.co.uk/messages?limit=10&offset=20
```

Another way to decrease the payload would be to only ask for certain parts of your resources' representation. Here's how facebook does it:

```
/joe.smith/friends?fields=id,name,picture
```

Remember that while using either of these methods, you have to provide a way for the client to discover each of the resources. You can't assume they'll just look at the parameters and start changing them in search of data. That would be a violation of the REST paradigm. Provide them with the necessary hyperlinks to avoid it.

I strongly recommend viewing [this presentation on RESTful API design](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design/) by [apigee](http://apigee.com/) (the screencast is called "Teach a Dog to REST"). Good practices and neat ideas to approach everyday problems are discussed there.

EDIT: The video has been updated a number of times since I posted this answer, you can check out the [3rd edition from January 2013](https://blog.apigee.com/detail/api_design_third_edition_video_slides)

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Let's assume when the server has 20 resources client fetched first 10 resources using limit 10 and offset 0 and before sending another request to fetch remaining resources if few of them deleted (1 to 5) from the server then how does client fetch 11th to 15th resources in this approach? because in the next fetch client shall request from offset 10 so it would miss the 11th to 15th data right. Is there another better approach to solve this without client keep track of deleted resources

Comment: @thavasidurai Here is some reading material on what to do instead of using LIMIT/OFFSET: https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset

Answer (score 12):

There are different ways in general by which one can improve the API performance including for large API sizes. Each of these topics can be explored in depth.

- Reduce Size Pagination
- Organizing Using Hypermedia
- Exactly What a User Need With Schema Filtering
- Defining Specific Responses Using The Prefer Header
- Using Caching To Make Response
- More Efficient More Efficiency Through Compression
- Breaking Things Down With Chunked Responses
- Switch To Providing More Streaming Responses
- Moving Forward With HTTP/2

Source: https://apievangelist.com/2018/04/20/delivering-large-api-responses-as-efficiently-as-possible/

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .net core
you have to try this magic package

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression
```

then use this line in `configureservices` in startup file

> services.AddResponseCompression();

then in `configure` function

> app.UseResponseCompression();