# C#: .NET HttpClient times out too fast

Tags: c#, .net, httprequest

I have a long list of API URL calls in `urlList` each of them returning quite an amount of JSON data.   Some of these take milliseconds, others may well take several minutes to complete. That's why I set the timeout to 30 minutes. For some reason the HttpClient instance times out after just 5 minutes and I have no idea why. When I open the same URLs in a browser window or in Postman it takes between 8 and 20 minutes, but they will eventually load while my C# code (see below) throws these exceptions:

> For some of the URLs I then get a CanceledException: Task
> CanceledException - System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A
> task was canceled.     at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)     at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at ...

```
private async Task<string> ProcessUrls(urlList)
{
    string userAndPasswordToken = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += this.ValidateRemoteCertificate;
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    this.httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    this.httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    this.httpclient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    this.httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Authorization",$"Basic {userAndPasswordToken}");

    SemaphoreSlim throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 20);
    List<Task> requests = new List<Task>();
    foreach (var url in urlList)
    {
        await throttler.WaitAsync();
        requests.Add(
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    result = await this.httpclient.GetAsync(url);
                }
                finally
                {
                    throttler.Release();
                }
            }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** I tried the same thing without the Semaphore, still, the same problem occurs - So I guess I can rule out that the Semaphore causes the issue.

What am I missing here? **(Note: The APIs I am accessing are not under my control)**

This is a .NET project (targetFramework net452), currently running in VS2019 on Win10.

Comment: Are you in full .net or .net core and what OS/platform?

Comment: A 30-minute transaction in HTTP is abusing the protocol. There are routers and proxies and things that are in your network path that may react badly. Consider [chunking your data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11725261/2791540)

Comment: @zaitsman: .NET, targetFramework net452. Currently running in VS2019 on Win10. Will add that information.

Comment: @John: I am aware of this but as I mentioned, the API is not under my control and these requests unfortunately cannot be chunked. But as the requests work in the browser/postman I assume it's not a problem with the network path.

Comment: Check the server part. In many servers, do not allow over than 5 mins connection without data transfer. If you cannot control the server, you have to ping some data to preserve the connection.

Comment: @donggas90: Thanks a lot, this actually is what causes the problem. In Wireshark I can clearly see Keep-Alive pings being sent from Chrome, but not from my .net app. Funnily enough, Postman (Chrome-Plugin) sends the Keep-Alive, thus it works. Postman (Standalone) does not - therefore it fails. However, so far I have not found a solution for sending Keep-Alive packets through an HttpClient connection. Any suggestions?